# Server Site Events (SSE) connection abort with firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, server-sent-events

I wrote a little Chat using SSE for loading new messages.

It is working fine with Chrome, Safari and Opera while Firefox closes the connection after a few retries. 
I'am using retry: 2000 (2s). Sometimes firefox is doing up to 10 events, sometimes only 1 or 2. I know from my serverstats, that more then 80% of my users are using firefox, so I need this working on firefox.

I'm using the latest version of firefox and I added a `console.log()` after every EventListener I'm using ('message', 'open', 'close').

Does anyone have an idea what to do?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What do you mean by "after a few retries"? Is your back-end server unstable and going down a lot? How frequently, time-wise and event-wise, is the connection being lost and retry required? Are you able to show the minimal back-end code, and JS front-end code, that will reproduce the problem? (Also exact firefox version, your OS, and if there are any proxy servers involved, might be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

think I solved the problem:

First I opend the EventSource in a function :

```js
function chat_read() {
  if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {  
    var source;
    source = new EventSource('?link=chat_stream'); 
  }
```

Now I tried to initialize the variable 'source' global (outside the function) and it is working now.

```js
var source;
function chat_read() {
  if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {  
    source = new EventSource('?link=chat_stream'); 
  }
```

Beside this I wrote a function which is looking for the SSE 'open' event still firering and if it is not, it will restart the SSE.